# htaccess redirect to port

Tags: apache-http-server, htaccess

I need to redirect subdomain.example.com -> subdomain.example.com:32400/web

My current htaccess is:

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://subdomain.example.com:32400/web [R=301,L]

AuthUserFile /var/.htpasswd
AuthName Welcome
AuthType Basic

require user someone

IndexOptions +ShowForbidden
ErrorDocument 401 /error401.html
ErrorDocument 404 /errorGeneric.html
ErrorDocument 500 /errorGeneric.html
```

However I keep getting 500 Internal Server errors with the redirect enabled, if the redirect is not active then the .htaccess works fine

Comment: If you get 500 errors, check the Apache HTTPD log file and see what the error was.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the `RewriteLog` directive, with `RewriteLogLevel` something above `0`?

Is it possible you have a rewriting deadlock; what service runs on port `32400`?

**Edit:** The availability of `RewriteLog` depends on the Apache version; for Apache 2.4+, the `LogLevel` directive rules rewrite logging as well (see [the LogLevel documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#loglevel)), e.g. `LogLevel rewrite:trace4`

Comment: It's a plex server on 32400, im almost certain mod_rewrite is on, how could i check

Comment: Do you have access to the Apache configuration, e.g. `/etc/apache2/`? Nowadays, usually there is a subdirectory `mods-enabled` which contains symbolic links for each enabled module; in my case there is one called `rewrite.load` which refers to `../mods-available/rewrite.load`.  And/or try `RewriteLog`.

Answer (score 0):

For simple cases, you don't need to use `mod_rewrite`.
It might be sufficient to use [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) instead; something like:

```
ProxyPass / http://subdomain.example.com:32400/web
ProxyPassReverse / http://subdomain.example.com:32400/web
```

(untested)

Answer (score 0):

If your error documents are to be served by Apache rather than your backend server process (which serves port 32400), you need to protect them from being rewritten; e.g.:

```
RewriteCond !^/error(401|Generic).html
```

before your `RewriteRule` (you can chain *1* to *n* conditions which will all need to be met for the following one `RewriteRule` to be executed).